# Fatal link error and can not find cfg_support_v1.lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, wdk

I am getting the following link error and cfg_support_v1.lib doesn't exist. Now sure what is causing this. Can someone help?

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\km\x64\\cfg_support_v1.lib'
```

Comment: Are you building a 64 bit application?

Comment: yes. Building debug x64.

Answer (score 2):

There are different versions of WDK 10: 10.0.10586, 10.0.14393 etc. To make it work properly you need to install Windows 10 SDK version that corresponds to your WDK version, e.g. if you have WDK 10.0.14393, you should also have SDK 10.0.14393 installed.

I got the same error when I had WDK 10.0.14393 installed but SDK was different version (10.0.10586). Installing SDK 10.0.14393 had fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of versions of WDK 10 installed on my system. I uninstalled them and re-installed latest WDK and SDK.

It works now.